# why is inner loop collect not returning results?

Tags: loops, common-lisp

I was trying to use standard loop facilities to collect into a result but it just returns nil. Why is this? it feels like this should work:

```
 (defun coll-intersects (bounds mv)
   (let ((res (list))
     (loop for x from (first bounds) to (+ (first bounds) (third bounds)) do
       (loop for y from (second bounds) to (+ (second bounds) (fourth bounds))
             if (not (member (cl-byte (aref mapa x y)) mv))
             collect (aref mapa x y) into res
             ))))
```

but no, i have to do this:

```
  (defun coll-intersects (bounds mv)
    (let ((res (list)))
     (loop for x from (first bounds) to (+ (first bounds) (third bounds)) do
       (loop for y from (second bounds) to (+ (second bounds) (fourth bounds))
            do
               (if (not (member (cl-byte (aref mapa x y)) mv))
                   (push (aref mapa x y) res))
            ))
      res))
```

why? i was really confused why the first one was not working

Comment: Is it a copy-paste typo? The `let` of the first example lacks a closing parenthesis: `(let ((res (list)))`. Your Lisp should warn you about a malformed let binding.

Comment: sorry, it was a recreation of something i tried. In the one i tried i was not missing that closing brace

Answer (score 6):

As Ehvince's answer says, the problem is that

```
(loop ...
      collect ... into x
      ...)
```

binds `x`.  The purpose of this construct is really so you can collect multiple lists:

```
(defun partition (l)
  (loop for e in l
        if (evenp e)
        collect e into evens
        else
        collect e into odds
        finally (return (values evens odds))))
```

for instance.

In the case where you want to collect a single list from nested loops and you care about order you can do this trick:

```
(defun sublist-evens (l)
  (loop for s in l
        nconcing
        (loop for e in s
              when (evenp e)
              collect e)))
```

Here the outer loop essentially `nconc`s together the results from the inner loop.  This can nest of course:

```
(loop ...
      nconcing
      (loop ...
            nconcing
            (loop ...
                  collect ...)))
```

will work.  It is also possible that `loop` is smart enough to keep a tail pointer to the list it's building with `nconc` / `nconcing`, although you'd have to check that.

However in cases where you want to build some list in-order from some deeply-nested loop (or any other search process) I find it's almost always more pleasant to use a [collecting macro](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#collecting-lists-forwards-and-accumulating-collecting) to do that (disclaimer: I wrote this one).  With such a macro the above `sublist-evens` function looks like this:

```
(defun sublist-evens (l)
  (collecting
    (dolist (s l)
      (dolist (e s)
        (when (evenp e) (collect e))))))
```

and

```
> (sublist-evens '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
(2 4 6)
```

And you can do better:

```
(defun tree-partition (tree)
  (with-collectors (evens odds)
    (labels ((search (it)
               (typecase it
                 (list
                  (dolist (e it)
                    (search e)))
                 (integer
                  (if (evenp it)
                      (evens it)
                    (odds it)))
                 (t
                  (warn "unexpected ~A" (type-of it))))))
      (search tree))))
```

and now

```
> (tree-partition '(((1 2 3) (4)) 5))
(2 4)
(1 3 5)
```

(And for hack value you can use [another macro](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#applicative-iteration-iterate) to express the above more concisely:

```
(defun tree-partition (tree)
  (with-collectors (evens odds)
    (iterate search ((it tree))
      (typecase it
        (list
         (dolist (e it)
           (search e)))
        (integer
         (if (evenp it)
             (evens it)
           (odds it)))
        (t
         (warn "unexpected ~A" (type-of it)))))))
```

Disclaimer: I wrote that macro too.)

Comment: nconcing, nice one! I'll also point on collecting utilities in Serapeum: https://github.com/ruricolist/serapeum/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#with-collector-collector-body-body

Comment: @Ehvince: yes, I think generations have reinvented things like `collecting`.  Mine came from Interlisp-D's `TCONC` or perhaps `DOCOLLECT` / `ENDCOLLECT` pair: I'm not sure which but I know I wrote the original on a D-machine.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the first snippet, with the `let` parenthesis corrected, simplified to be made reproducible:

```lisp
(defun coll-intersects (bounds mv)
   (let ((res (list))) ;; <-- third closing paren 
     (loop for x from (first bounds) to (+ (first bounds) (third bounds)) do
       (loop for y from (second bounds) to (+ (second bounds) (fourth bounds))
             if (evenp y)
             collect y into res
             ))))
```

Now when I enter it into the REPL, SBCL warns me about an unused `res`:

```
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable RES is defined but never used.
```

That's a big hint.

The issues I see:

- you use `do` for the outer loop, not collect, and you don't return `res`, so the functions always returns nil.
- `collect … into` presumably uses an internal variables, not *your* `res` :S In addition the loop doesn't say what to do with it. I added `finally (return res)` and I get results. You can also use `push` like in the second example. But it doesn't seem necessary to use `into`, just use `collect y`.
- it is usually not necessary to declare intermediate variables with an outer `let`.

Here's a simpler function that returns (dumb) results:

```lisp
(defun coll-intersects (bounds)
     (loop for x from (first bounds) to (+ (first bounds) (third bounds)) collect
       (loop for y from (second bounds) to (+ (second bounds) (fourth bounds))
             if (evenp y)
             collect y)))

(coll-intersects '(1 2 3 4))
((2 4 6) (2 4 6) (2 4 6) (2 4 6))
```

If you use `nconcing` instead of the first `collect`, you'll get a flat list (as pointed out by @tfb).

or:

```lisp
(defun coll-intersects (bounds)
   (let ((res (list)))
     (loop for x from (first bounds) to (+ (first bounds) (third bounds)) do
       (loop for y from (second bounds) to (+ (second bounds) (fourth bounds))
             if (evenp y)
             do (push y res)
             ))
     res))

(coll-intersects '(1 2 3 4))
(6 4 2 6 4 2 6 4 2 6 4 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, the return value from the function is the return value from the outer loop. It doesn't collect any values (the inner loop does) and thus most probably just returns a `nil`.

In your second example, your function explicitly returns the value of `res`.